# Manjaro can't login after remove ibus: appear the new login screen and no sessions to select

Tags: authentication, session, manjaro

After remove  and restarting the manjaro-KDE plasma, appear the new login screen and no sessions to select, so cannot log into the plasma, but can log in TTY, please help me, thanks : '<<
[image: no session so can't login]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

1. Login TTY by `Ctrl+Alt+f2`
2. ```
   sudo pacman -S sddm

   sudo pacman -S plasma kio-extras

   sudo pacman -S kde-applications

   sudo pacman -S kdebase

   systemctl enable sddm.service --force

   sudo pacman -S manjaro-kde-settings sddm-breath-theme manjaro-settings-manager-knotifier manjaro-settings-manager-kcm

   sudo pacman -S kde-applications

   sudo pacman -Syyu
   ```
3. `reboot`
4. `rename ~/.config/old_plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc to plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc`
5. `reboot`